# Reverse(s) function

Tags: c

*(I can't speak English very well, so I'm sorry for my mistakes)*

I'm learning C language, (I'm reading **The C Programming Language, second edition**). I can't complete exercise 4-13:

> Write a recursive version of the function reverse (s), which
>   reverses the string s in place.

I have to create this function without using pointers or things that I haven't studied yet.
This is my code:

```
void reverse(char s[])
{
     int c;
     static int i, k;
     i = 0;
     k = 0;
     if ((c = s[i]) != '\0')
     {
          i++;
          reverse(s);
     }
     if (c != '\0')
          s[k++] = c;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Could you help me, please?

Comment: *it doesn't work* - what is the error/problem ?

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? For some input, what is the expected and actual output? Have you tried stepping through the function, line by line, in a debugger?

Comment: Oh, and you reset the static variables `i` and `k` *every call*. Using `static` variables might work (once you fix the initialization issue), but it will make the function callable only once.

Comment: Is this function reversing the complete array?

Comment: You are using `s` which is of character type and assigning it to integer type `c` in the statement ---- `if ((c = s[i]) != '\0')` how this is going to work....

Comment: @JafferWilson Why won't it? In C, `char`s can be considered just the same as an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are resetting values of "i" and "j" to zero in the function.
static variables are initialized only once in the declaration statement.
Initialize the variables like this :

```
static int i=0, k=0;
```

You can also do away with initializing static variables to 0 as it would be done automatically. But it is a good programming practice to initialize variables during declaration.

Comment: which will only work for stdc=89 and later.

Comment: If `reverse` is called from some main function, then calling it the second time from main, it won't work anymore.

Comment: Just reset `i` and `k` in the recursion termina case will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

See @vikas answer, however, that will work only one time as to reverse a second string, i and k must be reset again. The following does that:

```
static int i, k;
void reverse(char s[]);

int main(void)
{
    char s[]="hello world";

    i= k= 0;
    reverse(s);

    return 0;
}

void reverse(char s[])
{
     int c;
     if ((c = s[i]) != '\0')
     {
          i++;
          reverse(s);
     }
     if (c != '\0')
          s[k++] = c;
}
```

Comment: This code give error. see this is your code execution http://ideone.com/9m3uv1

Comment: @Jaffer-Wilson, the code runs fine. There is no "runtime error". There may be a compile warning that reverse is not defined. See update of answer.

Comment: No still your output is runtime error for me:  http://ideone.com/9m3uv1

Comment: @Jaffer-Wilson, use a real compiler, not some on-line thing. In my VC2008 it runs fine and reverts the string.

Comment: @Jaffer-Wilson, `main` should return `0`, not 1. The on-line thing interprets the return value as the program reporting an error, even though it ran fine.

Comment: Great downvotes for a correct answer...

Comment: Your answer isn't correct. I have shared a link previously showing that your answer gives runtime error

Comment: `c` doesn't have to be an `int`. It can be a `char`. BTW, why not print the reversed string from `main`?

Comment: @Jaffer-Wilson, the code as currently published is correct. The on-line compiler to which you link reports the return value of `main` as indicating the program returned an error. I changed that to `return 0` as per unix convention and even the online compiler doesn't report an error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursive algorithms in C is a bad idea(with few exceptions,of course) because of the space cost and the poor performance when the compared to the equivalent iterative versions. That said,here's my recursive implementation of reverse(s):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void reverse(char s[],const size_t start,const size_t end);

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "C is a great programming language";
    reverse(s,0,strlen(s) - 1);
    printf("Reversed string: %s\n",s);  
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void reverse(char s[],const size_t start,const size_t end)
{
    if(start < end && NULL != s)
    {
        char tmp = s[end];
        s[end] = s[start];
        s[start] = tmp;
        reverse(s,start + 1,end - 1);
    }
}
```

PS: sorry for my bad english,i'm not a native speaker.